# Matrix Calculation .

Tags: matrices

$$P\pi=\pi$$
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0&0&0&0&1 \\
        1&0&0&0&0 \\
        \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0 \\
        \frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&0&0 \\
        \frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\times
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \pi_0 \\
              \pi_1 \\
               \pi_2 \\
        \pi_3 \\
        \pi_4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
        \pi_0 \\
              \pi_1 \\
               \pi_2 \\
        \pi_3 \\
        \pi_4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Why do $P\pi=\pi$ and $$\pi'P=\pi'$$ produce different result ?

Comment: What do you mean by different?

Comment: @draks... If $P\pi=\pi$  , I get $\pi_4=\pi_0$ and $\pi_0=\pi_1$ , so that $\pi_0=\pi_1=\pi_4$ . But this does not happen in $\pi'P=\pi'$

Comment: Because when you transpose you should get $\pi'P'=\pi'$

Comment: @d.k.o. Oh, i catch it .